# ArrayList.clear() problem in button onclicklistener that reads a firebase firestore database into an arraylist

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, arraylist

I have a firebase firestore database. I read this database into an arraylist everytime I click a button with an onclicklistener. However I need to reread this database everytime I click on this button depending on the changes in the database. Also I need to clear the arraylist into which I read the database everytime before I read the database. However when I use the arraylist.clear() command in android studio java I can not add any objects into the arraylist anymore. When I check the size of the arraylist it always appears as zero. I need to know the reason for this and how can I solve this problem? I add objects of a user defined class into the arraylist. Below is the code for my user defined class and the code snippet that causes this problem.

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import com.google.firebase.firestore.Exclude;

import java.io.Serializable;


public class Courses implements Serializable {

    
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    
    @Exclude
    private String id;

    
    private String courseName, courseDescription, courseDuration;

    public Courses() {
        
    }

    
    public Courses(String courseName, String courseDescription, String courseDuration) {
        this.courseName = courseName;
        this.courseDescription = courseDescription;
        this.courseDuration = courseDuration;
    }

   
    public String getCourseName() {
        return courseName;
    }

    public void setCourseName(String courseName) {
        this.courseName = courseName;
    }

    public String getCourseDescription() {
        return courseDescription;
    }

    
    public void setCourseDescription(String courseDescription) {
        this.courseDescription = courseDescription;
    }

    public String getCourseDuration() {
        return courseDuration;
    }

    public void setCourseDuration(String courseDuration) {
        this.courseDuration = courseDuration;
    }
} 

 

Btn121.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                

                coursesArrayList21.clear();
               

                db2.collection("Courses").get()
                        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots){
                                
                                if (!queryDocumentSnapshots.isEmpty()) {
                                    

                                    List<DocumentSnapshot> list = queryDocumentSnapshots.getDocuments();
                                    for (DocumentSnapshot d : list) {
                                        
                                        Courses c = d.toObject(Courses.class);
                                        
                                        coursesArrayList21.add(c);
                                    }
                                    

                                } else {
                                    
                                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity2.this, "No data found in Database", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            }
                        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                
                                
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity2.this, "Fail to get the data.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        });

                dummy1234 = coursesArrayList21.size();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity2.this,Integer.toString(dummy1234), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: Can you please also post how are you initiating `coursesArrayList21` variable? Is it normal arrayList or some variation of it? Are you performing any additional operation on it which may cause this, like sublist or something like this.

Comment: private ArrayList<Courses> coursesArrayList21;                                  
coursesArrayList21 = new ArrayList<>(); coursesArrayList21 variable is a normal arrayList whose elements are objects of Courses class.

Comment: Can you add a try catch around `Courses c = d.toObject(Courses.class);` statement, I think this statement might be throwing the exception, but that exception is silently getting catched by Firebase due to callback architecture. Can you check.

Also, by your statements, the arraylist is not adding after #clear function, can you remove that statment and verify that the #clear is the only culprit here.

Comment: When I remove the coursesArrayList21.clear(); statement everything works just fine. I mean when I remove this statement, I can add objects to the coursesArrayList21 variable.  So I do not think the problem has to do with the Courses c = d.toObject(Courses.class); statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the last Toast to determine the size of the list you get always 0 because you cleared the list and reading the DB is async, so the objects will be added after the Toast is shown.

Try showing the Toast, or printing to logcat, inside the method onSuccess, right after the for loop.

Comment: Thanks. Your suggestion solves the problem.

Comment: @gokseldemiradam I am glad it worked. Please consider marking my answer as accepted :)